# How can I authenticate role/permission info wso2 identity server to my service provider?

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am using Spring security SAML2.0 SSO with wso2IS 5.4.0. I have added claim for role into the wso2is inside the service provider. now i can get the User role in saml assertion.

Here i want to authenticate the user basis of their Role. I mapped application(service provider) url with some role in securityContext.xml

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" use-expressions="false" auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/saml/web/auth/denied">
<security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/home" access="ROLE_MEMBER"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/getUserDetails" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
</security:http>
```

Comment: Can you explain your requirement a little more? Do you want the roles to be included in saml assertion or you have already done that and you need something else?

Comment: Hi @Maduranga yes i want role should be included in saml assertion too and then after i want user should get access to my service provider(Application) on the basis of role which coming as part of saml assertion

Answer (score 1):

During service provider access, if you want to authenticate the user to the identity server based on their role then you can use XACML policy "authn_role_based_policy". If you use this XACML policy then, only the users who have specific roles will be allowed in the authentication flow and others will be denied. You could refer [writing XACML policy documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Writing+a+XACML+Policy+using+a+Policy+Template).

Comment: Hi @Nilasini i ahve done with XACML Policy and added my service provider(which i have registered named as App3) and role but its not working as i expecting

Comment: hi @Nilasini i configured XACML policy and it getting authenticated on the basis of Role, but what i want is user should get Authenticated and request will redirect to my service provider and there i have mapped some sort of functionality with some Roles of users, here ideally i want is like user role should be part of the assertion and i can able to authenticate on the basis of user role

Answer (score 1):

As you want to get the user's role in the saml assertion, what you need to do is add role claim (http://wso2.org/claims/role) to the requested claims list in service provider configuration as described [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider).

If you need to control the access from Identity Server side, follow the instructions provided by @Nilasini above. More information is available in [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Configuring+Access+Control+Policy+for+a+Service+Provider). Basically what you need to do is enable "Enable Authorization" in the service provider configuration and create a relevant XACML policy.

I'm not a expert of Spring SAML. So I'm not going to comment anything about how to control the access from Spring SAML using the user's roles, if that is what you want.